# Android's touch event doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a simple imageview with a colored background that when pressed change the color and at the end of the touch if it is outside the image area then it would return to the original color or else start another activity (like a button); so i decided to implement an onTouchListener in my activity using a kotlin lambda.
This is the code:

```
imageview.setOnTouchListener{ view: View, event: MotionEvent ->
        val rect = Rect(view.left, view.top, view.right, view.bottom)
        when(event.action){
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN->{
                view.setBackgroundColor(dark_color)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP-> {
                if (rect.contains(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())) 
                    startActivity(Intent(this, NewActivity::class.java)
                else{
                    view.setBackgroundColor(normal_color)
                }
            }
        }
        true
    }
```

And it works fine but while i was testing it i saw that the new activity was starting else if the touch is out of the image area, so i used the Log function to report the cordinates of the touch and i noticed that the cordinates (when MotionEvent.ACTION_UP was triggered) where different from the point that i was touching on the screen.
Is it possible that the system is bugged ?
(p.s. i tried also on the emulator and i had the same result and I can't use xml selectors)

Thanks for help!

Comment: I don&#39;t get why setting a touch listener on the imageView if you want to detect a touch event outside of the imageView area. I would set two touch events, one on the imageView to change the background color and another one on the image container (to return the background to the original color). This way you don't have to calculate if the touched point is inside or outside the imageView

Comment: My problem is that when i touch the imageview and i move the touch outside of of it (always while i'm touching) it start the new activity but it shouldn't. (the color of container background is different from the imageview's one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to create a selector. You set the selector as a background to your ImageView. So the selector manage the colour automatically (when the image is pressed or not). Then you set a listener on your ImageView to manage the click event. If the user moves his finger out of the ImageView area, the listener will NOT be triggered (it's automatically managed).

**In your Java code**

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
   public void onClick(...){
       // Start the Activity
   }
});
```

**in your XML**

```
<ImageView
   android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
//...
```

**my_selector.xml** (must be in the drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/default_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/default_not_pressed" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't specified it but in my app i have a large set of colors and thus the background's color change every time, i tried to change programatically the colors of some shape drawable and to use selector but it didn't work.

Comment: So instead of the selector, use an OnTouchListener but only to manage the colour. For the action on the button, keep the OnClickListener.